# Looking for active and supported maven plugin to compile less to css?

Tags: less, maven-3

I have a maven project where I use less to define the styling. I have not updated my tooling in a while, and while setting up a new laptop I am realizing the plugin I used to use for compiling less is not compatible with the newer versions of maven. I have been using the Gabrysbiz plugin;

```
<plugin>
    <!-- http://www.gabrys.biz/projects/lesscss-maven-plugin/1.1/index.html -->
    <groupId>biz.gabrys.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
     .
     .
     .
</plugin>
```

I get a missing class when I try and build using maven;

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin:1.2.1:compile (default) on project services: Execution default of goal biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin:1.2.1:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin:1.2.1:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/DirectoryScanner
> [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] realm =    plugin>biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin:1.2.1
> [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
> [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/biz/gabrys/maven/plugins/lesscss-maven-plugin/1.2.1/lesscss-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar
> [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/biz/gabrys/lesscss/compiler/1.2.2/compiler-1.2.2.jar
> [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R5/rhino-1.7R5.jar
> [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/biz/gabrys/lesscss/extended-compiler/2.1.0/extended-compiler-2.1.0.jar
> [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
> [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
> [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.4/commons-net-3.4.jar
> [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/sstanley/.m2/repository/biz/gabrys/maven/plugin-utils/1.4.0/plugin-utils-1.4.0.jar
> [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
> [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

With my debugging, it seems this plugin was counting on plexus-utils being provided by maven. However the newer versions of maven do not seem to include this. Unfortunately when I hunt up the [Github repo](https://github.com/gabrysbiz/lesscss-maven-plugin) it is marked as archived three years ago.

I've tried to find other plugins and this is what I have found so far;

- [marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin) : Github repo archived 5 years ago
- [Atlassian plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.lesscss/lesscss-maven-plugin) : This has a recent version published last year, however I have yet to find documentation on it anywhere yet.
- [Javalite plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javalite/activeweb-lessc-maven-plugin) : This has a recent version published last year. I can find [this documentation](https://javalite.io/lessc) for it.

Before I try and start digging in too deep with any of these, I thought I would check and see if there is something else I am missing. I can't find anything on the [LessCSS website](https://lesscss.org/) which I was surprised by.

Is there a lesscss maven plugin that is recommended?  I am sure there are many opinions on this. Would love to hear them before I invest the time to migrate to something new.

Comment: Have you considered using something like the `exec-maven-plugin` to instead run npm/yarn?  Or the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)?  I found [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986567/frontend-maven-plugin-when-it-runs-npm-run-build-cant-find-package-json-file).  If you have something like this you can use use `lessc` directly.

Comment: I haven't thought of trying that. But that is a really great idea. This eliminates the concerns over plugins staying up to date. I might play with the plugins a bit just to see how they work. But this is a nice fallback.